# Excel VBA 2007 Save workbook in read-only mode

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say a workbook is writeable, but is opened for read-only (through a read-only shortcut where the `/r` switch is used), and it has not been modified since someone has had it opened for read-only. How to allow them to save changes from VBA for Excel 2007 without re-opening?

I seemed to be able to do it with 2003 but not with 2007. In 2003 this seemed to work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess (Excel.XlFileAccess.xlReadWrite)
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess (Excel.XlFileAccess.xlReadOnly)
```

But in 2007 no longer. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "read-only shortcut"?

Comment: A shortcut where the /r switch is used, so that a writeable file can be opened for read-only. This allows more than one person to view the file at once, while at the same time allows someone to make changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` to some temp filename, then `Kill` the old file, then rename the temp file to the old path using `Name`?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid creating or destroying any files, I'd like to stick with the same instance if possible.

Comment: Good ol' moving the goalposts... Please write all of your requirements in your question.

Comment: I was just hoping to save the read-only instance without creating or removing as I'd done before. If this is not possible then that's fine.

Comment: If it turns out this goal can't be accomplished I will still mark that solution as the answer.